# Wordpress PHP Slider not deleting images as I delete images from the post

Tags: php, wordpress, image, slider, wordpress-theming

So right now, I am running some PHP code to turn images from a Wordpress post into a slider element.

```
<?php 

$ticker = 0;

$attachments= get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
$full_img_url[$ticker] = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
?>

<img class="mySlides" src="<?php echo $full_img_url[$ticker]; ?>" >

<?php
$ticker ++;
}
?>


<button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094; </button>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-right"onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095; </button>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.display = "none";
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

My problem appears when I remove an image from the post.

[The WordPress post](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/430851883280760852/445926649431851010/unknown.png)

[The slider element that should be there.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/430851883280760852/445926874065928192/unknown.png)

[The one that shoulds be](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/430851883280760852/445926972049063957/unknown.png)

So when I remove an image from the post it isn't removed from the slider elements.

Comment: Do you know how i could delete it?

Comment: But how would I delete the one that I remove in the post? Like a match of some sorts right?

Comment: Deleting the image with wp_delete_attachment doesn't seem to work. Could it be related to the img tag not deleting when I delete the image? I have no clue how I would manually delete the img tag.

Comment: I would like to know too.

Comment: What you mean? this is basically a template for a wordpress page to use a slideshow to show comic pages.